# No option to update WP in client's backend

Tags: installation, upgrade

I want to upload a new theme to my client's site, but in her backend it says she's on the latest version of WP, but it's 3.5.1. Like the last developer set it so it doesn't update. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Does the user account you are logged in with have admin rights?  Verify on the user settings page. Quite likely it is limited to editor or author.

Comment: @jdm2112 I'm in as an admin. The backend is confusing to me. There's no appearance tab in the menu to change themes, or plugins tab. I have FTP access so I can upload new files, but I'm not sure which ones to upload.

Comment: If you are able to view plugins, look to see if an admin plugin is present.  Some devs like to customize the backend with an admin theme and these menu choices might be hidden via CSS.  They might also be removed via the functions file or another method.  Do you have backups in place?  I would spin up a copy of the site locally or in a dev directory to make your changes.

Answer (score 1):

It does seems that installation was customized in some way, either in regard to user account or user interface.

If that is option at all I would politely inquire with last developer about customization performed. Beats digging through code.

As for core update specifically — the “manual” way would be to delete old core files and upload a new core version in exact place.

Of course make backups before you touch anything and be careful that you don't loose any configs or user–generated files. If admin is customized it wouldn't surprise me if the directory structure has tweaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

People hide update notification and button from normal user because we don't know what they will do with that. Especially when the new version of wp, plugin haven't been checked with our theme yet.

There is some kind of hack that can make user can't update the core from the admin side.

1. Editing the `wp-config.php` by adding `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );` will disable the core update.
2. Add function to the `functions.php' of theme to disable core update and version check.

   ```
   add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_core_updates');
   function remove_core_updates()
   {
   if(! current_user_can('update_core')){return;}
   add_action('init', create_function('$a',"remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );"),2);
   add_filter('pre_option_update_core','__return_null');
   add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core','__return_null');
   }
   ```

You can check your client's `wp-config.php` or `functions.php`.

From your comment I see that the Appearance is missing from your menu. You can try manually add `themes.php` after `http://yoursite.com/wp-admin` to access Appearance. They were hidden by adding this function to `functions.php`:

```
function remove_menus(){

  remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                  //Dashboard
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
  remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                 //Media
  remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
  remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                 //Appearance
  remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                //Plugins
  remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                  //Users
  remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                  //Tools
  remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );        //Settings

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

Comment: And yet it’s a very harmful practice. Without updates your site quickly gets vulnerable for attacks with exploits - so anyone can easily destroy it, use it for sending spam, and so on... Never block updates, never...